# Change App.js for a published Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am developing an Add-In, and I need to constantly debug it.

At the moment I follow this path:
I use Visual Studio, publish the .app file and load it in SPO App Catalog.
Then in a Test Site I remove the old App and add the new one (waiting 2-3 minutes for installation)

Then I open the new Add-in only to see that in App.js I have an error!

How can I speed up this test pattern?
Can I change the App.js code for a published app?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be using Visual Studio [SPFastDeploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCurranMVP.SPFastDeploy) extension.

You can right-click on your file, select `Fast Deploy` and your `App.js` will be replaced with a newer version without full re-deployment. To make it work, in your Visual Studio app project you should provide valid url to your site.

Comment: Good point, I've downloaded and installed it. However when right clicking on `App.js` there insn't the menu "Fast Deploy to Sp app". My project has Site Url setted as: `https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sviluppo.app`. Another problem could be that in my Add-in I am accessing Lists on the host-site, so if I use Visual Studio Debugging I get all (expected) errors: "List 'XXX' does not exist at site with URL 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sviluppo.apps'

Comment: Please refer to this [article](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013/03/making-it-easy-to-develop-and-debug.html) on how to add menu item